# sequelizejs: how todo database migration with partition

Tags: sequelize.js

Databases like mysql, mariadb, sql server support partition.

Does sequelizer support table partition?

From the documentation I can't find the answer, so the answer is no?

Has anyone enable it manually?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been out here a while, but I thought I'd post an answer just in case someone else was looking. At present, sequelize does not support partitions. There is a feature request for [Table partitioning](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7673) which covers adding it to the library, but no one has been assigned to it in over a year and no milestones are marked.

There is a pull request to add [PostgreSQL table partitioning](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/8995) that has not been merged in. It doesn't help in the particular cases of MySQL, MariaDB or SQL Server, but may be usable as a jumping off point for developing an add on to include the functionality for those platforms.

**As we don't know much about the original desired outcome of this question, all my potential solutions involve some amount of speculation:**

You could potentially use sequelize [raw queries](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/) to manually manage partitioning by defining the table name explicitly within the model

```
sequelize.define('my_table', {
...
}, {
  tableName: 'my_explicit_table_name'
});
```

and then executing something like

```
sequelize.query("ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS my_explicit_table_name RENAME TO my_table_20181018");
sequelize.query("CREATE TABLE my_explicit_table_name");
```

on an daily basis if you wanted to partition on a day-by-day interval.

Similar could be achieved using the sequelize [migration framework](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/migrations/) convenience functions combined with the raw queries to achieve some version of partitioning.

Unfortunately, as sequelize only allows for a single string to be specified for the table name, both of these would mean losing access to any tables beyond the base through the model. There may be some leeway to update the table name directly in the model on a per-request basis e.g.

```
instance.models.my_model.tableName = my_new_tablename
```

but that is pure speculation with no testing to back it up.